# Laptop Hangs on Shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, shutdown

```
Laptop: Thinkpad P50
CPU: Intel i7-6820HQ (8) @ 3.600GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA Quadro M1000M 

Xubuntu 20.04 LTS
```

I have an issue where after hitting shutdown, my computer will stay kind of on. It seems to go through the whole shutdown process, I get past all grub screens, screen turns off, and then it stays on just enough to where I'll have to force off the machine to use it again.

I'm not sure how to go at troubleshooting this situation. I found one common solution to ubuntu hanging here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/508029/ubuntu-14-04-stuck-on-shutdown), however the problem persisted. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No USB or other external peripheral?

Comment: @Didier just unplugged them all to check, issue persists

Comment: I haven't really used Ubuntu in a while, so I may be completely off the ballpark here, but isn't there an option to clear the swap on shutdown, same as clear pagefile on exit in Windows? If so, and if it's enabled, depending on the size of it and how full it is when you shut your Ubuntu down, it could take time.

Comment: OS? Distro? Release? FWIW,  I have been using a P50 with Ubuntu 16.04 and a P53 with Ubuntu 19.10 without such problems.

Comment: @xenoid oh my bad, im on Xubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Have you had any other problems on your P50? I also had this other issue (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245351/xubuntu-20-04-lts-cant-change-login-screen-resolution-thinkpad-p50/1247121#1247121) that persisted across every distro ive used so far. Not saying its related to my current issue, just curious on your input on that too, because that one seemed hardware/driver related

Comment: Sounds like this recent kernel bug [Failing to shutdown/power off or reboot on AMD Ryzen CPUs on kernel versions 5.3.0-52 and later](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe/+bug/1880041) in 18.04 but probably also applies to 20.04. Can you add kernel version `uname -r` to your question? If related there should have been an update in the last week or so.

Comment: Checking further, in 20.04 kernel 5.4.0.37 or higher should be ok. In 18.04 it was fixed with 5.3.0.59.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reinstalling the OS.